# sort a list of @Sortable objects in descending order

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a class

```
@Sortable(includes = ['date'])
class Item {
  // other fields not relevant to this question
  Date date
}
```

If I sort a `List` of these objects it will sort them in ascending order based on the `date` field. Is there a way to sort them in descending order instead? I know I could just call `reverse()` on the result of the ascending sort, but this seems a bit inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:

```
def items = [
new Item(date: new Date(40000)),
new Item(date: new Date(1000)),
new Item(date: new Date(200000)),
new Item(date: new Date(00100)),
]

items.sort { a, b -> b <=> a }    

items.sort(true, Collections.reverseOrder())
```